# How do I make a badge counter similar to Ad-blocker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I want to improve my extension and the best way for me to do that right now is probably to add a badge to show that it's blocking things. I just can't wrap my head around how badges work, here is my extension (https://github.com/Cybo1927/Anti-Click-Tracking) and thanks for the help!

I've tried checking popular extensions like uBlock Origin, AdGuard, and Adblock Plus but I can't seem to figure it out.

I hope for it to show the amount of things blocking (for all the attributes if possible)

Comment: you want to use [browserAction.setBadgeText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserAction/setBadgeText)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `browser.browserAction.setBadgeText`

Code example:

```
var clicks = 0;

function increment() {
  browser.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: (++clicks).toString()});
}

browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(increment);
```

[For more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserAction/setBadgeText)

[You can check this example too](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/blob/master/tabs-tabs-tabs/background.js)